# Can the rank of harmonic maps decrease far from the boundary?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-topology, elliptic-pde, singularity-theory, harmonic-functions

Let $\mathbb D^n$ be the closed unit ball in $\mathbb R^n$. Let $f:\mathbb D^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a real-analytic orientation preserving immersion, and let $\omega:\mathbb D^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be the harmonic map corresponding to the Dirichlet problem imposed by $f$, i.e. $\omega|_{\partial \mathbb D^n}=f|_{\partial \mathbb D^n}$

> Does $\text{rank}(d\omega)\ge n-1 $ everywhere on $\mathbb D^n$?

A perhaps easier question: Suppose that $d\omega_p$ is singular, and that $p  \in \mathbb D^n$ lies in the closure of $\{ p \in \mathbb D^n \, \, | \,\, \det(d\omega_p)>0 \}$. Is $\text{rank}(d\omega_p)\ge n-1 $?

I already know two things:

> 1. There is an open neighbourhood of $\partial \mathbb D^n$ where $\text{rank}(d\omega)\ge n-1 $.
> 2. $d\omega$ is invertible almost everywhere on $\mathbb D^n$.

Indeed, point $1$ follows from
$p \in \partial \mathbb D^n  \Rightarrow \text{rank}(d\omega_p)\ge \text{rank}\big(d(\omega|_{\partial \mathbb D^n})_p\big)= \text{rank}\big(d(f|_{\partial M})_p\big)=n-1.$

For point $2$,  note that $d\omega$ is singular on as set of positive measure if and only if it is singular everywhere on $\mathbb D^n$: Since $\omega$ must be real-analytic, so is $\det d\omega$, and the zero-set of a real-analytic function which is not identically zero has measure zero.

However $d\omega$ cannot be singular everywhere, since

$$ \int_{\mathbb D^n} \det d\omega = \int_{\mathbb D^n} \det df>0.$$

---

*A comment on the case of dimension $2$:*

Where $n=2$, the question is whether $\omega$ can have a critical point: Write $f=(f_1,f_2)$ for $f_i:\mathbb D^2 \to \mathbb R$, and similarly $\omega=(\omega_1,\omega_2)$. Then $df_i \neq 0$ everywhere on $\mathbb D^2$.  However, this fact alone does not imply that $d\omega_i \neq 0$ on $\mathbb D^2$. Here is a counter example:

Set $f_i(x,y)=x-2y^2$. Then $\omega_i(x,y)=x^2-y^2+x-1$, and $d\omega_i=(2x+1,-2y)$ is zero at the point $(-\frac{1}{2},0)$.

To get a counter-example to the question, we need $d\omega_1,d\omega_2$ to vanish at the same point *simultaneously*; we cannot take $f_1=f_2$, since then $f=(f_1,f_2)$ won't be an immersion.